# What should be in the NGINX location block to refer to only the home page?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Apparently, this can be used to serve the home page for say example.com/:

```
location = / {

}
```

But when I do this, only the index.html file is served - the accompanying css file does not load (nor do images, etc). The same happens if I use:

```
location = /index.html {

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to refer to ONLY the home page and then I need another location block to refer to everything else.

Source: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/nginx-location-examples/

Comment: Post complete `server` block config.

Comment: The home page is a collection of URIs, and `/` is just the first one to be requested. So `location /` is the correct syntax to use.